# Retry Logic for LINQ-TO-SQL on SQL Azure - Efficient implementations?

Tags: linq-to-sql, azure-sql-database

I have a fairly large web application using LINQ-TO-SQL running in Azure, and I'm experiencing Transient errors from SQL-Azure and therefore need to implement retries.  I'm aware of the [Transient Fault Handling Framework](http://windowsazurecat.com/2011/02/transient-fault-handling-framework/) and several sites that give examples how to use it, but it looks like you have to wrap every one of your LINQ queries in something similar to this:

```
RetryPolicy retry = new RetryPolicy<MyRetryStrategy>(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
Result = retry.ExecuteAction(() =>
{
   … LINQ query here...
});
```

With hundreds of LINQ queries in my data layer, this seems really messy, plus the fact that a lot of times the query isn't actually executed until the results are enumerated.   For example, most of my functions in my data layer return an IQueryable<> up to the business layer, (which makes them more flexible than returning a List).  So that would mean you have to litter your business logic layer with database retry logic - ugly.

So I guess in order to keep the retry logic in the data layer, I would have to put .ToList()'s on all my queries so they are executed right there, and not in the layer above.

I really wish there was a way to implement retry logic in some base class and not have to change all of my queries.  Seems like EF would have this problem too.

**Is the real answer to try and talk the SQL-Azure team to do the auto-retries, so we dont have to worry about that in our code?**

Answer (score 1):

After needing to implement something like this, I went ahead and made it a library: https://github.com/daveaglick/LinqToSqlRetry (MIT licensed and available on NuGet).

You can retry `SubmitChanges()` calls by writing `SubmitChangesRetry()` instead:

```
using(var context = new MyDbContext())
{
  context.Items.InsertOnSubmit(new Item { Name = "ABC" });
  context.SubmitChangesRetry();
}
```

You can also retry queries by using the `Retry()` extension method:

```
using(var context = new MyDbContext())
{
  int count = context.Items.Where(x => x.Name == "ABC").Retry().Count();
}
```

The specific retry logic is controllable by policies. Under the hood, the retry mechanism looks like:

```
int retryCount = 0;
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        return func();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        TimeSpan? interval = retryPolicy.ShouldRetry(retryCount, ex);
        if (!interval.HasValue)
        {
            throw;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(interval.Value);
    }
    retryCount++;
}
```

Understand that the function in the call to `func()` and the `retryPolicy` object are provided based on usage. This just gives you an idea what's going on during the retry loop. Just look in the repository for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not aware of a good solution, as LINQ to SQL doesn’t allow us to intercept queries. But a little code refactor may help. Something like (pseudo code):

```
public Result QueryWithRetry(IQueryable query)
{
      RetryPolicy retry = new RetryPolicy<MyRetryStrategy>(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)); 
     (() => 
     { 
       return retry.ExecuteAction(query);
     }
}
```

Now it is slightly easier to invoke this method:

Result = QueryWithRetry(… LINQ query here...);

However, it is still needed to modify your code and change every query.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: That helps a little, but wouldn't I still have to worry about the queries that don't actually execute until later in the code where they are enumerated?  Therefore I would have to really investigate each query and figure out where the database is actually being called.

Comment: Sorry, I can’t understand you very well. Do you mean you’re worried if something goes wrong, it will be more difficult to find the source of the issue because the wrapped the query inside a retry framework? In this case, I would like to suggest you to set a break point on retry.ExecuteAction, and step through the code.

Comment: No, I just mean adding the retry logic to an existing app with hundreds of queries will be a difficult task - mainly because the database call doesn't necessarily happen in the linq-to-sql query in the data layer.  Execution of the query may be delayed until the IQueryable is actually enumerated - which could happen up in the business layer.  There just doesnt seem to be a clean solution to this problem.

Comment: I’m not aware of a better solution. Actually even when connecting to a local database, it is also recommended to use a retry logic. If we have implemented retry logic before, it would be much easier to migrate our project to SQL Azure. Retry logic is not specific to SQL Azure. This is a best practice when we want to connect to a database and make the solution robust.